# Logarithms Question

Tags: logarithms

Find the logarithms of the following numbers to the base 2:
32

I know 32 is 2^5. What is the format of the answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Find the logarithms of the following numbers to the base 2:
>
> (...)
>
> What is the format of the answer?

This is usually written as:
$$\log_{2} 32$$

> I know 32 is 2^5.

This is indeed equal to $5$ for exactly that reason:
$$\log_{2} 32 = 5 \iff 2^5 = 32$$
Or in general (for $a>0$ and $a \ne 1$, $x>0$):
$$\log_{a} x = y \iff a^y = x$$